# Structured bindings width

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, type-traits, c++17, structured-bindings

Is it possible to determine how many variable names should I to specify in square brackets using structured bindings syntax to match the number of data members of a plain right hand side `struct`?

I want to make a part of generic library, which uses structured bindings to decompose arbitrary classes into its constituents. At the moment there is no variadic version of structured bindings (and, I think, cannot be for current syntax proposed), but my first thought is to make a set of overloadings of some function `decompose()`, which performs decomposition of `struct` parameter into a set of its constituents. `decompose()` should be overloaded by number of parameter's (which is `struct`) data members. Currently `constexpr if`  syntax also can be used to dispatch this. But how can I emulate something similar to `sizeof...` operator for above purposes? I can't use `auto [a, b, c]` syntax somewhere in SFINAE constructions, because it is *a decomposition declaration* and AFAIK any declaration cannot be used inside `decltype`, also I cannot use it for my purposes in the body of lambda functions because lambda functions cannot be used inside template arguments too.

Surely I want to have builtin operator (with syntax like `sizeof[] S`/`sizeof[](S)` for `class S`), but something like the following is also would be acceptable:

```
template< typename type, typename = void >
struct sizeof_struct
{

};

template< typename type >
struct sizeof_struct< type, std::void_t< decltype([] { auto && [p1] = std::declval< type >(); void(p1); }) > >
    : std::integral_constant< std::size_t, 1 >
{

};

template< typename type >
struct sizeof_struct< type, std::void_t< decltype([] { auto && [p1, p2] = std::declval< type >(); void(p1); void(p2);  }) > >
    : std::integral_constant< std::size_t, 2 >
{

};

... etc up to some reasonable arity
```

Maybe `constexpr` lambda will allow us to use them into template's arguments. What do you think?

Will it be possible with coming *Concepts*?

Comment: AFAIK lambda won't become available inside `decltype`, not because they're not `constexpr`, but because each and every time the lambda syntax is used a brand new type is created, which would muddle template instanciation logic a *lot*.

Comment: @Quentin it is sad. I think it will be good, if value of any literal type can became a non-type template parameter. I sure there would be mangling issues, but instances of such a templates may be forbidden for any kind of export. In the case they are still can be useful for generic code.

Comment: I found [partial answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463646/) on my question in my previous q&a-s here (it is correct for classes w/o (even empty) bases). But what the answers to the rest part of question?

Comment: [Here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142804/) is a possible use case.

Comment: @Quentin Whatever the committee does with lambdas in unevaluated contexts, they will not allow you to SFINAE on statements inside lambdas. That's just a giant can of worms.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, and this is close enough to reflection that I doubt the committee will try to address it before reflection comes in.

Comment: @T.C. I read the `2.3 Customization` section of the structured binding (I think latest) [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r2.pdf) and I don't know how to interpret it - does this means that there will be specialization of `std::tuple_size` for each structure that has structured bindings?

Comment: @W.F. No, it means that if you want to allow your structure to be decomposed, and the default doesn't cut it (e.g., it doesn't have all-public data members, those data members don't come from the same class, not all of them should participate, or you want a different type for some of them), you specialize `tuple_size`/`tuple_element`/`get`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
struct two_elements {
  int x;
  double y;
};

struct five_elements {
  std::string one;
  std::unique_ptr<int> two;
  int * three;
  char four;
  std::array<two_elements, 10> five;
};

struct anything {
  template<class T> operator T()const;
};

namespace details {
  template<class T, class Is, class=void>
  struct can_construct_with_N:std::false_type {};

  template<class T, std::size_t...Is>
  struct can_construct_with_N<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::void_t< decltype(T{(void(Is),anything{})...}) >>:
  std::true_type
  {};
}
template<class T, std::size_t N>
using can_construct_with_N=details::can_construct_with_N<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>;

namespace details {
  template<std::size_t Min, std::size_t Range, template<std::size_t N>class target>
  struct maximize:
    std::conditional_t<
      maximize<Min, Range/2, target>{} == (Min+Range/2)-1,
      maximize<Min+Range/2, (Range+1)/2, target>,
      maximize<Min, Range/2, target>
    >
  {};
  template<std::size_t Min, template<std::size_t N>class target>
  struct maximize<Min, 1, target>:
    std::conditional_t<
      target<Min>{},
      std::integral_constant<std::size_t,Min>,
      std::integral_constant<std::size_t,Min-1>
    >
  {};
  template<std::size_t Min, template<std::size_t N>class target>
  struct maximize<Min, 0, target>:
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t,Min-1>
  {};

  template<class T>
  struct construct_searcher {
    template<std::size_t N>
    using result = ::can_construct_with_N<T, N>;
  };
}

template<class T, std::size_t Cap=20>
using construct_airity = details::maximize< 0, Cap, details::construct_searcher<T>::template result >;
```

This does a binary search for the longest construction airity of `T` from 0 to 20.  20 is a constant, you can increase it as you will, at compile-time and memory cost.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a22ccd6fe5c91a5).

If the data in your struct cannot be constructed from an rvalue of its own type, it won't work in C++14, but I believe guanteed elision occurs in C++17 here (!)

Turning this into structured bindings requires more than a bit of a pile of manual code.  But once you have, you should be able to ask questions like "what is the 3rd type of this `struct`" and the like.

If a `struct` can be decomposed into structured bindings without the `tuple_size` stuff being done, the airity of it determines how many variables it needs.

Unfortunetally `std::tuple_size` is not SFINAE friendly even in C++17.  But, types that use the `tuple_size` part also need to ADL-enable `std::get`.

Create a namespace with a `failure_tag get<std::size_t>(Ts const&...)` that `using std::get`.  Use that to detect if they have overridden `get<0>` on the type (`!std::is_same< get_type<T,0>, failure_tag >{}`), and if so go down the `tuple_element` path to determine airity.  Stuff the resulting elements into a `std::tuple` of `decltype(get<Is>(x))` and return it.

If that fails, use the above `construct_airity`, and use that to figure out how to use structured bindings on the type.  I'd probably then send that off into a `std::tie`, for uniformity.

We now have `tuple_it` which takes anything structured-binding-like and converts it to a tuple of references or values.
Now both paths have converged, and your generic code is easier!

Comment: The default version of structured binding permits more than aggregates; the class at issue need only 1) has all public data members and 2) have them all be direct members of the same class.

Comment: You may use multiplication by 2 until arity 2^n failed. Then apply binary search to higher half of 2^n range of arities.

Comment: As I mentioned above it has been already done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463646/). Also I think much more simplier linear approach will be better for practical use (in sense of time of compilation).

Comment: This method unfortunately fails with structs that have plain arrays, because of brace elision. With `struct with_arr { int a, b, c, d[5]; };`, `construct_airity` reports 8, but you need 4 names to deconstruct it. [Proof](https://godbolt.org/z/WzYnMW)

Comment: @joao yep.  Wafch for barry's http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p1061r0.html proposal.

Answer (score 2):

Also there is a linear approach to find the "aggregate arity" (though, also under the same strict enough circumsances, as in the accepted answer):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

struct filler { template< typename type > operator type && (); };

template< typename aggregate, 
          typename index_sequence = std::index_sequence<>, 
          typename = void >
struct aggregate_arity
        : index_sequence
{

};

template< typename aggregate, 
          std::size_t ...indices >
struct aggregate_arity< aggregate, 
                        std::index_sequence< indices... >, 
                        std::void_t< decltype(aggregate{(indices, std::declval< filler >())..., std::declval< filler >()}) > >
    : aggregate_arity< aggregate, 
                       std::index_sequence< indices..., sizeof...(indices) > >
{

};

template< std::size_t index, typename type >
constexpr
decltype(auto)
get(type & value) noexcept
{
    constexpr std::size_t arity = aggregate_arity< std::remove_cv_t< type > >::size();
    if constexpr (arity == 1) {        
        auto & [p1] = value;
        if constexpr (index == 0) {
            return (p1);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } else if constexpr (arity == 2) {
        auto & [p1, p2] = value;
        if constexpr (index == 0) {
            return (p1);
        } else if constexpr (index == 1) {
            return (p2);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } else if constexpr (arity == 3) {
        auto & [p1, p2, p3] = value;
        if constexpr (index == 0) {
            return (p1);
        } else if constexpr (index == 1) {
            return (p2);
        } else if constexpr (index == 2) {
            return (p3);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } else /* extend it by yourself for higher arities */ {
        return;
    }
}

// main.cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

namespace
{

using S = struct { int i; char c; bool b; };

S s{1, '2', true};

decltype(auto) i = get< 0 >(s);
decltype(auto) c = get< 1 >(s);
decltype(auto) b = get< 2 >(s);

static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(i), int & >{});
static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(c), char & >{});
static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(b), bool & >{});

static_assert(&i == &s.i);
static_assert(&c == &s.c);
static_assert(&b == &s.b);

}

int
main()
{
    assert(i == 1);
    assert(c == '2');
    assert(b == true);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Currently argument of `get()` cannot have `const` top level type qualifier (i.e. `type` can be `&&` and `&`, but not `const &` and `const &&`), due to the [bug](http://wg21.link/LWG2770).

[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0avUYB7CCF950mVx).

Comment: hi, i have trouble getting this to work with derived types: struct A{}; struct B : A{int i;} a; auto& i = get<0>(a); this does not compile: " the number of identifiers must match the number of array elements or members in a structured binding declaration" do you have any idea how to get around that?

Comment: @Fabian Maybe this works: `B b; auto & [a, i] = b; static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(a), A & >::value, "!"); static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(i), int & >::value, "!");`?

Comment: @Fabian Seems, this is impossible to achieve with `aggregate_arity` approach. There is substantial difference in number of "placeholders" between aggregate initialization and decomposition for structured bindings.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i discarded the inheritance approach and tried something else (which also fails :() please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675239

Answer (score 1):

Approach taking the ideas from Yakk and applying [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) features like concepts and templated lambdas, to make it more compact:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct anything {
    template<class T> operator T() const;
};

template<class T, std::size_t... Ints>
concept Constructible = requires {
    T{ anything<Ints>{}... };
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto is_constructible() {
    constexpr auto unpack = [&]<std::size_t... Ints>(std::index_sequence<Ints...>) {
        return Constructible<T, Ints...>;
    };
    return unpack(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template<class T, std::size_t N = 0u, bool found = false>
constexpr auto find_struct_arity() {
    constexpr auto constructible = is_constructible<T, N>();

    if constexpr (found && !constructible) {
        return N - 1;
    }
    else if constexpr (constructible) {
        return find_struct_arity<T, N + 1, true>();
    }
    else {
        return find_struct_arity<T, N + 1, found>();
    }
}
```

It's a linear search for constructibility, and if it no longer works for `N` braces, it returns `N - 1` as a result. Example usage ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/5c9WrMaGv)):

```
struct foo2 {
    int a;
    double b;
};
struct foo5 {
    int a;
    double b;
    foo2 c;
    char* d;
    std::array<int, 10> e;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(find_struct_arity<foo2>() == 2);
    static_assert(find_struct_arity<foo5>() == 5);
}
```