# How to use C++ template magic in order to pattern match on type

Tags: c++

The desire is to have only one wrapper for all `typename T` which support structured bindings for example via `tuple_size` and `tuple_element`  without runtime overhead(`contexpr`s, SFINAE). There's a function `encode` with accepts `T obj` as an argument and calls `encode_impl` with more specific arguments and type arguments.

The article https://playfulprogramming.blogspot.com/2016/12/serializing-structs-with-c17-structured.html uses a bunch of arity functions to achieve the same result. But as far as I understand tuples provide `std::tuple_size` which is possible to utilize.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>


class Aa {
    public:
        Aa(int a1_, int a2_): a1(a1_), a2(a2_) {}

        template<std::size_t N>
        decltype(auto) get() const {
            if constexpr (N == 0) return a1;
            else if constexpr (N == 1) return a2;
        }

    private:
        int a1;
        int a2;
};

class Bb {
    public:
        Bb(Aa a_, int b_): a(a_), b(b_) {}

        template<std::size_t N>
        decltype(auto) get() const {
            if constexpr (N == 0) return a;
            else if constexpr (N == 1) return b;
        }

    private:
        Aa a;
        int b;

};

namespace std {
    // Aa
    template<>
    struct tuple_size<Aa> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2> {};

    template<std::size_t N>
    struct tuple_element<N, Aa> {
        using type = decltype(std::declval<Aa>().get<N>());
    };

    // Bb
    template<>
    struct tuple_size<Bb> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2> {};

    template<std::size_t N>
    struct tuple_element<N, Bb> {
        using type = decltype(std::declval<Bb>().get<N>());
    };
}

template <size_t N>
using size = std::integral_constant<size_t, N>;

template<typename T>
void encode(T t) {
    encode_impl<?std::tuple_size<T>?()>(T t, ?std::tuple_size<T>);
}

template<?>
encode_impl(T t, ?) {
    std::cout << "It works";
}
```

The expectations of resolving the issue are the understanding of notation which must be used to compile the code snippet. Right now you can see `?` in many places.

If it's not possible to do using `std::tuple_size` then alternative solutions are welcome. Arity function from the article for classes don't work but that's a bit different question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768517/structured-bindings-width/39779537#39779537 It’s also relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to apply the return values of `some_type::get<i>()` as the arguments of a function?

Off the top of my head you would write `encode` and `encode_impl` something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void encode(T const& t, std::ostream& os)
{
  encode_impl(t, os, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value>{ });
}

template
<typename T, std::size_t... I>
void encode_impl(T const& t, std::ostream& os, std::index_sequence<I...> const)
{
  constexpr auto last = sizeof...(I) - 1;
  os << "{ ";
  [[maybe_unused]] int const temp[] = 
    { ((os << t.template get<I>() << (I != last ? ", " : " ")), 0)... };
  os << "}" << std::endl;
}
```

This disgusting looking pack expansion in `encode_impl` is using the comma operator just to force evaluation of its left hand operand and discard the result, then evaluate the literal `0` and store it in the dummy array `temp`. The pack expansion is used to initialize an array so that the arguments are evaluated in the correct order (left to right).

UPDATE:
Okay so I think what you want is to make your own type trait test `is_tuple_like` that returns true if the type `T` is "tuple-like" which just requires that the expression `std::tuple_size<T>::value` is well formed and the expression `declval<T&>().template get<std::size_t(0)>()` is well formed. From there you can write a function that prints the elements of "tuple-like" types and if any of those elements are tuple-like, print their elements, recursively. Here's what I came up with:

```
template
<
  typename T,
  typename tp_enabled =
    std::void_t
    <
      decltype(std::tuple_size<T>::value),
      decltype(std::declval<T&>().template get<std::size_t(0)>())
    >
>
constexpr auto
is_tuple_like(int const)noexcept->bool
{
  return true;
}

template
<typename T, typename tp_arg>
constexpr auto
is_tuple_like(tp_arg const)noexcept->bool
{
  return false;
}

template<typename T>
auto encode(T const& t, std::ostream& os)->
std::enable_if_t<is_tuple_like<T>(0)>
{
  encode_impl(t, os, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value>{ });
  os << std::endl;
}

template
<bool is_last, typename T>
auto
encode_one(T const& t, std::ostream& os)->
std::enable_if_t<!is_tuple_like<T>(0)>
{
  os << t << (is_last ? " " : ", ");
}

template
<bool is_last, typename T>
auto
encode_one(T const& t, std::ostream& os)->
std::enable_if_t<is_tuple_like<T>(0)>
{
  encode_impl(t, os, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value>{ });
  os << (is_last ? " " : ", ");
}

template
<typename T, std::size_t... I>
void encode_impl(T const& t, std::ostream& os, std::index_sequence<I...> const)
{
  constexpr auto last = sizeof...(I) - 1;
  os << "{ ";
  [[maybe_unused]] int const temp[] =
    { (encode_one<I == last>(t.template get<I>(), os), 0)... };
  os << "}";
}

int main () {
    auto a = Aa(1, 1);
    encode(a, std::cout);
    auto b = Bb(a, 1);
    encode(b, std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{ 1, 1 }
{ { 1, 1 }, 1 }
```

UPDATE 2: So it turns out the above implementation of `is_tuple_like` compiles fine on GCC and the latest version of Clang (8.0.0) but fails to compile on Clang 7.0.0 so here is a version that works on Clang 7.0.0 it uses a variable template instead of a function template:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

class Aa {
    public:
        Aa(int a1_, int a2_): a1(a1_), a2(a2_) {}

        template<std::size_t N>
        decltype(auto) get() const {
            if constexpr (N == 0) return a1;
            else if constexpr (N == 1) return a2;
        }

    private:
        int a1;
        int a2;
};

class Bb {
    public:
        Bb(Aa a_, int b_): a(a_), b(b_) {}

        template<std::size_t N>
        decltype(auto) get() const {
            if constexpr (N == 0) return a;
            else if constexpr (N == 1) return b;
        }

    private:
        Aa a;
        int b;
};


namespace std {
    // Aa
    template<>
    struct tuple_size<Aa> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2> {};

    template<std::size_t N>
    struct tuple_element<N, Aa> {
        using type = decltype(std::declval<Aa>().get<N>());
    };

    // Bb
    template<>
    struct tuple_size<Bb> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2> {};

    template<std::size_t N>
    struct tuple_element<N, Bb> {
        using type = decltype(std::declval<Bb>().get<N>());
    };
}

template
<typename T, typename tp_enabled = std::void_t<>>
constexpr bool is_tuple_like = false;

template
<typename T>
constexpr bool 
is_tuple_like
<
  T, 
  std::void_t
  <
    decltype(std::tuple_size<T>::value),
    decltype(std::declval<T&>().template get<std::size_t(0)>())
  >
> = true;

template<typename T>
auto encode(T const& t, std::ostream& os)->
std::enable_if_t<is_tuple_like<T>>
{
  encode_impl(t, os, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value>{ });
  os << std::endl;
}

template
<bool is_last, typename T>
auto
encode_one(T const& t, std::ostream& os)->
std::enable_if_t<!is_tuple_like<T>>
{
  os << t << (is_last ? " " : ", ");
}

template
<bool is_last, typename T>
auto
encode_one(T const& t, std::ostream& os)->
std::enable_if_t<is_tuple_like<T>>
{
  encode_impl(t, os, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value>{ });
  os << (is_last ? " " : ", ");
}

template
<typename T, std::size_t... I>
void encode_impl(T const& t, std::ostream& os, std::index_sequence<I...> const)
{
  constexpr auto last = sizeof...(I) - 1;
  os << "{ ";
  [[maybe_unused]] int const temp[] =
    { (encode_one<I == last>(t.template get<I>(), os), 0)... };
  os << "}";
}

int main () {
    auto a = Aa(1, 1);
    encode(a, std::cout);
    auto b = Bb(a, 1);
    encode(b, std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'd like to make it in the same style as `print_struct` from the article which accepts for example `size<2>` as the third argument.
Regarding your code snippet, there's an `error: template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression encode_impl(t, os, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>>{ });`
Clang version is `Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)`
Here's the code I try to compile on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8nbsqYWG)

Comment: Ah I forgot the `::value` after `std::tuple_size<t>` it should compile now. Also I was printing each element backwards. But I have also realized that my answer is incomplete because it does not address structures that contain substructures ie `Bb` I'll be adding to it shortly.

Comment: There is a [code](https://pastebin.com/7aMJmyLC) I try to compile and an [error](https://pastebin.com/eQn8aSJ3) I receive. It must be a typo somewhere cause the error shows `tuple_size<int>` call which is invalid for sure. It might be that I copy pasted it wrong though.

Comment: The code from your pastebin compiles fine on GCC 8.3 as well as Clang 8.0 (used compiler explorer) however I am getting the same error on Clang 7.0, and so I did some digging and this is indeed a bug with earlier versions of Clang not handling expression SFINAE properly with function templates in certain cases. Let me see if I cant make a different version of `is_tuple_like` that works on Clang 7.0