# C++ number of structure elements (member variables)

Tags: c++, c

I have an autogenerated structure type which is a container of various elements. Since the number of elements can vary (based on how the structure is generated), I would like to know (ideally in compilation time) the number of elements of currently generated structure.

Based on some input, the structure may look like this:

```
typedef struct _autoGenStruct {
    int a,
    int b,
    int c
} autogenStruct
```

or like this:

```
typedef struct _autoGenStruct {
    int a,
    int b,
    int c,
    int d
} autoGenStruct
```

In the first case, I expect to get 3 elements, in the second 4. The element type is always integer. Is there a way how to do this in C/C++? Thanks.

Comment: Considering that you really can't use the member count in any way, why do you need it? What problem is that counter supposed to solve?

Comment: As for a possible solution to the counter-problem, can't the program that does the auto-generation also include a macro or something that contains the count?

Comment: do you do the structure generation on your own or is it shipped to you? Since they are auto-generated, you can also auto-generate the control information (enums or constants containing the number of elements in each structure).

Comment: [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) might interest you.

Comment: Yes, that would be my idea as well, to include a counter to the generation of the structure. But before doing that, I was wondering if there is a direct way in C, without touching the generator.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463646/arity-of-aggregate-in-logarithmic-time. Might be a good dupe. There's also https://github.com/felixguendling/cista/blob/master/include/cista/reflection/arity.h.

Comment: Also, please clarify whether you need a solution that works in C++, or in C, or in both. Each of those cases would have wildly different answers.

Comment: @MaxLanghof C++ is sufficient, but if there is a general solution which works in both cases, I will gladly see it.

Answer (score 3):

If all elements are integers then you can probably assume there is no padding in your structures so the number of member variables should be simply:

```
auto elements = sizeof(_autoGenStruct) / sizeof(int);
```

Comment: it works only if all elements are of the same type. according to the topic owner the structure is container of various elements. They might be different

Comment: @rhaport "The element type is always integer."

Comment: Nice. But how can I be sure that there is no padding in the structure. That depends on the compiler and the system used, or? But, yes, all elements are of the same int type.

Comment: Even if there is no padding, there can be alignment requirements on the structure. Particularly if the elements are `short int` instead of `int`

Comment: Alignment is the main problem, e.g if sizeof(int) = 4 bytes and alignment = 8 bytes then this method will fail when the no of elements is odd.

Comment: @pisoir It would be odd for a compiler to add padding between `int` subobjects because `int` is supposed to be the "natural" size for the architecture. But there's no formal guarantee in the standard regarding any sort of padding.